# Volley Image Loader ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: android, android-volley

I am using volley image loader for loading image on my project from server. But in some cases i am getting the following error and application crashes.

```
            java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
          at java.util.LinkedList$LinkIterator.next(LinkedList.java:124)
          at com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader$4.run(ImageLoader.java:440)
          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

I can't find reason for the error and the solution for this. Please help me.

Global.java

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.example.volley.LruBitmapCache;
import java.util.HashMap;
public class Global extends Application{
    public static final String TAG = Global.class.getSimpleName();
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
    private static Global mInstance;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }
    public static synchronized Global getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }
    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }
        return mRequestQueue;
    }
    public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
        getRequestQueue();
        if (mImageLoader == null) {
            mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(this.mRequestQueue,new LruBitmapCache());
        }
        return this.mImageLoader;
    }
    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
        req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }
    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }
}
```

LruBitmapCache.java

```
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader.ImageCache;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.support.v4.util.LruCache;

public class LruBitmapCache extends LruCache<String, Bitmap> implements ImageCache {
    public static int getDefaultLruCacheSize() {
        final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);
        final int cacheSize = maxMemory / 8;

        return cacheSize;
    }

    public LruBitmapCache() {
        this(getDefaultLruCacheSize());
    }

    public LruBitmapCache(int sizeInKiloBytes) {
        super(sizeInKiloBytes);
    }

    @Override
    protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap value) {
        return value.getRowBytes() * value.getHeight() / 1024;
    }

    @Override
    public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
        return get(url);
    }

    @Override
    public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
        put(url, bitmap);
    }
}
```

Code to loading image into network view

```
ImageLoader myLoader = Global.getInstance().getImageLoader();
networkImageView.setImageUrl(thumbnailURL, myLoader);
myLoader.get(thumbnailURL, new ImageLoader.ImageListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        //Set Error image
    }
    @Override
    public void onResponse(ImageLoader.ImageContainer response, boolean isImmediate) {
        if (response.getBitmap() != null) {
            //Set BitMap
        }
        else{
            //Set Loading image
        }
    }
});
```

My Costume network view image view listener

```
public class NetworkImageViewListener {

    private final String TAG_THUMBNAIL_ERROR = "THUMBNAIL_ERROR";
    private final String TAG_THUMBNAIL_RECEIVED = "THUMBNAIL_RECEIVED";

    private String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();


    private boolean original_image_loaded = false;
    public void loadImage(final Context context,final String url,final NetworkImageView networkImageView, final int approx_width, final int approx_height,final boolean thumbnail, final ProgressBar progressBar, final boolean is_Store){
        networkImageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        final int picture_not_found = R.drawable.ic_profile_picture_not_found;
        final int picture_not_loaded = R.drawable.ic_profile_picture_not_loaded;

        if (url != null && !url.equals("null")&& !url.equals("NULL")&& !url.equals("")) {
            final String originalURL = getImageUrl(url, approx_width, approx_height);

            final Bitmap cacheImage = getCacheImage(context, originalURL);
            if (cacheImage==null) {

                if(progressBar!=null){
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                if (thumbnail) {
                    final String thumbnailURL = getImageThumbnailUrl(url, approx_width, approx_height);

                    ImageLoader thumbnailLoader = Global.getInstance().getImageLoader();
                    networkImageView.setImageUrl(thumbnailURL, thumbnailLoader);
                    thumbnailLoader.get(thumbnailURL, new ImageLoader.ImageListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            if(progressBar==null){
                                networkImageView.setImageResource(picture_not_found);
                            }
                            networkImageView.setTag(TAG_THUMBNAIL_ERROR);
                            load_Original(context, originalURL, networkImageView, progressBar, is_Store, picture_not_loaded);
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(ImageLoader.ImageContainer response, boolean isImmediate) {
                            if (response.getBitmap() != null) {
                                networkImageView.setImageBitmap(response.getBitmap());
                                networkImageView.setTag(TAG_THUMBNAIL_RECEIVED);
                                load_Original(context, originalURL, networkImageView, progressBar, is_Store, picture_not_loaded);
                            } else if (progressBar==null) {
                                networkImageView.setImageResource(picture_not_found);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                else{
                    load_Original(context,originalURL,networkImageView,progressBar,is_Store,picture_not_loaded);
                }
            } else {
                networkImageView.setImageBitmap(cacheImage);
            }
        } else {
            networkImageView.setImageResource(picture_not_found);
        }
    }
    private void load_Original(final Context context,final String originalURL,final NetworkImageView networkImageView, final ProgressBar progressBar, final boolean is_Store,final int picture_not_loaded){
        final Drawable temp = networkImageView.getDrawable();
        final String imageviewTag = (String) networkImageView.getTag();
        ImageLoader imageLoader = Global.getInstance().getImageLoader();
        networkImageView.setImageUrl(originalURL, imageLoader);
        imageLoader.get(originalURL, new ImageLoader.ImageListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                if (progressBar != null) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                if (temp != null && imageviewTag != null && !imageviewTag.equals(TAG_THUMBNAIL_ERROR)) {
                    networkImageView.setImageDrawable(temp);
                } else if (temp != null && imageviewTag != null && imageviewTag.equals(TAG_THUMBNAIL_RECEIVED)) {
                    networkImageView.setImageDrawable(temp);
                } else {
                    networkImageView.setImageResource(picture_not_loaded);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(ImageLoader.ImageContainer response, boolean shouldAnimate) {
                if (response.getBitmap() != null) {
                    if (progressBar != null) {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                    networkImageView.setImageBitmap(response.getBitmap());
                    if (is_Store) {
                        setCacheImage(context, originalURL, response.getBitmap());
                    }
                } else {
                    networkImageView.setImageDrawable(temp);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private static String getImageUrl(String url, int aprox_width, int aprox_height){
        int index = url.lastIndexOf('/');
        String path = url.substring(0, index);
        String file_name =  url.substring(index + 1);
        String result = path+"/"+aprox_width+"/"+aprox_height+"/"+file_name;
        return result;
    }

    private static String getImageThumbnailUrl(String url, int approx_width, int aprox_height){
        int index = url.lastIndexOf('/');
        String path = url.substring(0, index);
        String file_name =  url.substring(index + 1);
        String result = path+"/"+approx_width+"/"+aprox_height+"/tbnil"+"/"+file_name;
        return result;
    }

    private String profile_picture_folder_name = "PP";
    private void setCacheImage(Context context, String url, Bitmap bitmap){
        try {
            if (!getCacheDirectory(context).equals("")) {
                String filename = getFileName(url);
                File folder = new File(getCacheDirectory(context)+"/"+profile_picture_folder_name+"/");
                if (!folder.exists()) {
                    folder.mkdir();
                }
                if (folder.exists()) {
                    File dest = new File(folder, filename);
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dest);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, out);
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.developer(TAG,e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    private Bitmap getCacheImage(Context context,String url){
        try {
            if (!getCacheDirectory(context).equals("")) {
                String filename = getFileName(url);
                File folder = new File(getCacheDirectory(context)+"/"+profile_picture_folder_name+"/");
                if (folder.exists()) {
                    FileInputStream fis = null;
                    File imageFile = new File(folder, filename);
                    if (imageFile.exists()) {
                        fis = new FileInputStream(imageFile);
                        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.developer(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
    private String getCacheDirectory(Context context){
        String cachePath="";
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState()) || !Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable()) {
            if (context.getExternalCacheDir() != null && context.getExternalCacheDir().exists()) {
                cachePath = context.getExternalCacheDir().getPath(); // most likely your null value
            }
            else if (context.getCacheDir() != null && context.getCacheDir().exists()) {
                cachePath = context.getCacheDir().getPath();
            }
        } else {
            if (context.getCacheDir() != null && context.getCacheDir().exists()) {
                cachePath = context.getCacheDir().getPath();
            }
        }
        return cachePath;
    }

    public String getFileName(String urlStr) {
        return urlStr.substring(urlStr.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, urlStr.length());
    }
}
```

Comment: post the full stacktrace and the code related to

Comment: @Yazan :I have added as you said.

Comment: i don't think it's good idea to make instance from the class that extends `Application`, right? this could be related ?

Comment: @Yazan could you please edit it to proper way if you can or suggest an example? I couldn't understand what you mean.

Comment: a second thought i don't think this is issue, since you are using `mInstance=this;` and not creating a new instance of `Global`

Comment: I have added image loader class also

Comment: Reason of the problem I found that the concurrent calling of image loader. I am using this for loading thumbnail first and after thumbnail loading completed with success or error, then load high quality image, Is there any other way to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement two ImageLoaders, one for the thumbnails and another one for the full-res images.
Modify your `RequestQueue` singleton as follows:

```
//..
private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
private ImageLoader mThumbLoader;
//...
// Then in constructor
mThumbLoader = new ImageLoader(mRequestQueue, new ImageLoader.ImageCache() { ... });
mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(mRequestQueue, new ImageLoader.ImageCache() { ... });

// And then you build two getters
protected ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
    return mImageLoader;
}

protected ImageLoader getThumbLoader() {
    return mThumbLoader;
}
```

If you invoke the `mThumbLoader` for the thumbnails and `mImageLoader` for the full res images it will work fine.