# How to diagnose ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: android, android-volley, concurrentmodification

I'm getting the following error in a crashlytics report and I'm having a little trouble figuring out where it's coming from or how to resolve it.

The reason I'm confused - is the crash seems to reference the Volley library it's-self, not any code I've actually written (nothing in the crash seems to point to any of my code).

Does anyone know how or what I might be able to do to resolve this crash?

Any suggestions are GREATLY appreciated.

### Fatal Error:

```
Fatal Exception: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
       at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:787)
       at java.util.HashMap$ValueIterator.next(HashMap.java:819)
       at com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader$4.run(ImageLoader.java:464)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5527)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
```

### Source:

```
public class VolleyManager {
    private static final String TAG = VolleyManager.class.getSimpleName();

    /** Number of network request dispatcher threads to start. */
    private static final int DEFAULT_NETWORK_THREAD_POOL_SIZE = 4;

    private static VolleyManager mInstance;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
    private static Context mContext;

    private VolleyManager(Context context) {
        mContext = context.getApplicationContext();
        mRequestQueue = getRequestQueue();
    }

    public static synchronized VolleyManager getInstance(Context context) {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new VolleyManager(context);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            File cacheDir = new File(FMCacheManager.getCacheBaseDir(mContext));

            String userAgent = "volley/0";
            try {
                String packageName = mContext.getPackageName();
                PackageInfo info = mContext.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(packageName, 0);
                userAgent = packageName + "/" + info.versionCode;
            } catch (NameNotFoundException ignore) {
            }

            HttpStack stack = new HurlStack();
            Network network = new BasicNetwork(stack);

            HandlerThread mHandlerThread = new HandlerThread(TAG, android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
            mHandlerThread.start();

            ResponseDelivery delivery = new ExecutorDelivery(new Handler(mHandlerThread.getLooper()));
            RequestQueue queue = new RequestQueue(new DiskBasedCache(cacheDir), network, DEFAULT_NETWORK_THREAD_POOL_SIZE, delivery);

            queue.start();

            mRequestQueue = queue;
        }
        return mRequestQueue;
    }


    public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
        getRequestQueue();
        if (mImageLoader == null) {
            mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(this.mRequestQueue,
                    new LruBitmapCache());
        }
        return this.mImageLoader;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
        if (req != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "request: " + req.getUrl());

            // set the default tag if tag is empty
            req.setTag(FMUtils.isNullOrEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);

            getRequestQueue().add(req);
        }
    }

    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the stack trace suggests that the crash happens in `ImageLoader`'s `run()` method and that it has to do with iterating over a `HashMap`.

You can see (some version of) `ImageLoader.java` [in here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/ba7d701bc2a0fa657422242537ace9bd63b14798/src/com/android/volley/toolbox/ImageLoader.java#437). There's this for-each loop:

```
for (BatchedImageRequest bir : mBatchedResponses.values()) {
    for (ImageContainer container : bir.mContainers) {
        // If one of the callers in the batched request canceled the request
        // after the response was received but before it was delivered,
        // skip them.
        if (container.mListener == null) {
            continue;
        }
        if (bir.getError() == null) {
            container.mBitmap = bir.mResponseBitmap;
            container.mListener.onResponse(container, false);
        } else {
            container.mListener.onErrorResponse(bir.getError());
        }
    }
}
```

Now, if an another thread modifies the `mBatchedResponses.values()` or `bir.mContainers` while they are being iterated, a `ConcurrentModificationException` will occur. They are not "thread safe" collections.

There's [this other recent discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35479128/volley-image-loader-concurrentmodificationexception) which points out that separate `ImageLoader` instances should be used for any simultaneous (parallel) image loading operations. Fernando Jascovich writes:

> You have to implement two ImageLoaders, one for the thumbnails and
>   another one for the full-res images.

So you could check if you start any parallel image download operations in your own code, have a look at that other discussion and follow the recommended approach.

As for a more generic answer to "How to diagnose ConcurrentModificationException": See the stack trace, look at the exact code file name and line number. If it's inside a for-each loop iterating over a collection you are probably modifying the collection in another thread at the same time. This might happen only occasionally and go unnoticed for a long time. The same exception also happens when modifying the collection inside the said for-each loop as explained e.g. [in this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816196/java-util-concurrentmodificationexception-in-non-multithreaded-program).

Comment: I'm calling / creating ImageLoaders in two classes/places - my FMUtils class: http://pastebin.com/y3xkxSSz and my AdsController class: http://pastebin.com/0aHBz3WW


BTW - I really appreciate your help with this - it's driving me crazy trying to fix this (I can't replicate it - but I keep getting crash reports about it) 

Also - the stacktrace, where should I be looking?  com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader ? (I'm just a little confused because the stacktrace doesn't seem to mention a line number of my code - instead it seems to point to the Volley library its self [I think])

Comment: Any ideas how I might resolve this? (I posted a few code snippets above)

Comment: I'm not actually familiar with Volley so I can't comment on best practices etc. It's funny though that using a singleton "VolleyManager" like you have seems to be exactly what is recommended in tutorials, but then it may lead to a `ConcurrentModificationException`. I also can't really say if Fernando's advice is the "best practise" for using Volley, but having a look at the `ImageLoader.java` it does make sense. So you could try making your `VolleyManager` have two separate `ImageLoader` instances: one for `FMUtils` and one for `AdsController`.

Comment: It's anyway obvious that the exception occurs inside `ImageLoader.java` and it's the `mBatchedResponses` `HashMap` that's being iterated and modified concurrently. (As the crash log specifies a `HashMap` and `bir.mContainers` is a `LinkedList`.) It's iterated in [batchResponse()](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/master/src/main/java/com/android/volley/toolbox/ImageLoader.java#450) and modified in [cancelRequest()](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/master/src/main/java/com/android/volley/toolbox/ImageLoader.java#344).